# Adding custom validation to input field

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, validation

I am trying to add custom validation on my text type of input. I'm using Angular, btw.

Here is code:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label">text</label>
  <input type="text" name="text" class="form-control" id="text_test" ng-blur="saveProgress()" ng-model="formData.text" placeholder="Any text" required>
  <p class="form-group-note">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
</div>
```

I would like to add 2 validations: 1) It cannot be empty 2) Min-length for the text is 6 characters. I want this validation to be triggered when submit button on my web app is pressed.

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: `if(string.length > 5){}`? As for when it's called, you haven't provided and JS code, so you're on your own with that bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with HTML input tag attributes.

```
<input type="text" pattern="^.{5,}" required>
```

`required` attribute tells that input cannot be empty

`pattern="^.{5,}"` prevents input to be shorter than 6 characters.

This validation will be triggered if your `<input>` is inside a `<form>` like:

```
<form action="">
  <input type="text" pattern="^.{5,}" required>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

If you would like to read more on the topic refer to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Data_form_validation)

Comment: A good solution, but somewhat unreliable on a few browsers (Safari, and older IE if you're unlucky enough to deal with them): http://caniuse.com/#search=pattern Personally I'd still stick with JS validation until Safari catches up.

Answer (score 0):

Try this hope it will work

```
   <input type="text" name="text" class="form-control" id="text_test" ng-blur="saveProgress()" ng-model="formData.text" placeholder="Any text" required>
```

Controller:

```
   $scope.submit = function() {
        if ($scope.formData.text) {
            if ($scope.formData.text.length >= 6) {

                //save code
            } else {
                $scope.errormessage = "Min length failed ,it should be greater than 5"

            }
        } else {
            $scope.errormessage = "Textfield Empty"
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

To validate while typing use ng-minlength,

```html
 <input type="text" name="text" class="form-control" id="text_test" ng-blur="saveProgress()" ng-model="formData.text" placeholder="Any text" required="required" ng-minlength="6">
```

To validate only after pressing button ,

```html
 <input type="text" name="text" class="form-control" id="text_test" ng-blur="saveProgress()" ng-model="formData.text" placeholder="Any text"> 


<button ng-click="submit()"/>
```

On your controller:

```js
 $scope.submit = function() {
        if ($scope.formData.text) {
            if ($scope.formData.text.length >= 6) {

                //save code
            } else {
                $scope.errormessage = "Min length should be greater than 5"

            }
        } else {
            $scope.errormessage = "Text field is required"
        }
    };
```